# Copying data from Table on MySQL Server to the local MySql Database table in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to copy some columns from one table located on the MySQL Server, to a local MySQL database using C#. How can I do it ?

I'm not sure if i should use MySQLDataAdapter or Bulk Copy (which i don't understand much).

Answer (score 0):

Bulk copy would be an easier method. It takes a previously created datatable and uploads it to the database.

You can use the following code to help. The below code allows you to return a datatable:

```
public DataTable FillTable(string sql)
{

    MySqlCommand sqlQuery = new MySqlCommand();

    cmd.Connection = ;// insert the connection details of the DB to transfer FROM
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    { 
        conn.Open();                
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        conn.Close();
    }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fillTable: "+ ex.Message);
        }

    return dt;
}
```

Then using the following you can send the data over to your new database:

```
Datatable newTable = FillTable("SELECT * FROM MyOldTable");

using (MySqlBulkCopy destination = new MySqlBulkCopy("MyNewDatabaseConnection String"))
{
    destination.DestinationTableName = "myNewTable";

    try
    {
        destination.WriteToServer(newTable);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Reference [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx)